# How to expand and collapse divs one after one if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 divs. If I click on 1st div, this should increase the width of this div. Now, if I click on the second div, it should decrease the width of 1st div and increase the width of 2nd div and vice versa. But my code is not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".glyphicon-eye-open").click(function() {
    if ($("div").is('.main, .main22')) {
      $(this).closest('div').removeClass('main');
      $('.item').not(this).removeClass('main22');
      $('.item').not(this).removeClass('main');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('main');
      $(this).closest('div').addClass('main22');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="item">A <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></div>
    <div class="item">B <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></div>
    <div class="item">C <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></div>
    <div class="item">D <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></div>
    <div class="item">E <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></div>
    <div class="item">F <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></div>
  </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.item{border:1px solid #ccc; min-height: 200px; width:48%; float: left; position: relative; margin:1%;}
.main-container{margin-top:20px;}
.item .glyphicon-eye-open{position: absolute; right: -10px; top:-10px; font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer;}
.main{width:98%;}
```

Comment: how you are increasing the width of divs?

Comment: @sony updated css code, please check

Comment: You can use the accordion method of jquery instead https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Use `parent` and `css` methods to change the height

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $(".glyphicon-eye-open").click(function(){
      $('div').css('height','20px')
        $(this).parent().css('height','50px')
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="item">A <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">g</i></div>
        <div class="item">B <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">g</i></div>
        <div class="item">C <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">g</i></div>
        <div class="item">D <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">g</i></div>
        <div class="item">E <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">g</i></div>
        <div class="item">F <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">g</i></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I want to increase width of clicked div and decrease width of already clicked div..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Is this what you're looking for?

The width of the element you click will increase, while the rest will go back to normal.

```js
$(function(){
$(".div").on("click",function(){
$(this).css("max-width","200px");
$(".div").not($(this)).css("max-width","100px");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div" style="max-width:100px;border:1px solid red">Div 1</div><br>
<div class="div" style="max-width:100px;border:1px solid red">Div 2</div><br>
<div class="div" style="max-width:100px;border:1px solid red">Div 3</div><br>
<div class="div" style="max-width:100px;border:1px solid red">Div 4</div><br>
<div class="div" style="max-width:100px;border:1px solid red">Div 5</div><br>
```